# Can react-chessground work with chessground@8 or above?

Tags: reactjs, chess, lichess

I created a react app where react-chessground works with chessground@7.16.13

And now I'm tryin to upgrade chessground to version 8.2.1, but there are 8 errors like:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-chessground/node_modules/chessground/chessground.js 1:0-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './api' in 'C:\User\file\node_modules\react-chessground\node_modules\chessground'
Did you mean 'api.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './api' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
```

The same for './config', './state', './wrap', './events', './render', './svg', './util'.

This is my code:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import Chessground from "react-chessground";
import "./chess.css";
import "./styles.css";
import "./theme.css";
import toDests from "./to-dests";
import { Chess } from "chess.js";

export default function Board() {
    const [fen, setFen] = useState(
        "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"
    );

    const chess = new Chess(fen);
    const turnColor = chess.turn() === "w" ? "white" : "black";
  
    const handleMove = ( from, to ) => {
      chess.move({ from, to, promotion: "q" });
      setFen(chess.fen());
    };

    return (
        <div className="justChessBoard">
          <div>
            <Chessground
              fen={fen}
              turnColor={turnColor}
              onMove={handleMove}
              movable={toDests(chess)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or it just doesn't work together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chessground](https://github.com/lichess-org/chessground) control released the first v8.0.0-beta1 version on Jun 16, 2021. See [tags](https://github.com/lichess-org/chessground/tags) for more details.

At the same time the last release of [react-chessground](https://github.com/ruilisi/react-chessground) control is from [Apr 18, 2018](https://github.com/ruilisi/react-chessground/tags).

Usually major version increment means breaking at least some APIs. Authors (or community) needs to update react-chessground control.

Since the react-chessground control was updated quite some time ago, it is possible that it is not being developed anymore. But there are [52 forks](https://github.com/ruilisi/react-chessground/network/members) of this repository. Maybe one of recent ones does work with v8.